# Codename one - Android build error

Tags: codenameone, build.xml

I encounter an error when trying to send my app to the server for building (android). Netbeans outputs the following message (actual username removed):

```
Prompting for password
Building for username: <actualUsernameHere>
/home/user/NetBeansProjects/OPKP/build.xml:338: The attribute  can't be empty 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Build.xml (around line 338):

```
<target name="build-for-android-device" depends="clean,copy-android-override,copy-libs,jar,clean-override">
    <codeNameOne 
        jarFile="${dist.jar}"
        displayName="${codename1.displayName}"
        packageName = "${codename1.packageName}"
        mainClassName = "${codename1.mainName}"
        version="${codename1.version}"
        icon="${codename1.icon}"
        vendor="${codename1.vendor}"
        subtitle="${codename1.secondaryTitle}"          

        targetType="android"
        keystoreAlias="${codename1.android.keystoreAlias}"
        keystore="${codename1.android.keystore}"
        certPassword="${codename1.android.keystorePassword}"
        automated="${automated}"
        /> //line 338
</target>
```

Also Codename One settings won't show up...

It stared when I received this error:

```
Cannot use a cn1lib with java version greater then the project java version
```

At the same time Netbeans had a problem with JavaFX. So I downloaded the latest jdk and add a hint in codename one: java.version -> 8. This fixed both issues, but now I can't build my app.

EDIT:
Codename_settings.properties file (some info are hidden, but are present in the file):

```
#
#Tue Jul 11 14:27:58 CEST 2017
codename1.ios.appid=
codename1.ios.release.provision=
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.arg.rim.obfuscation=false
codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
foobarfoo=This is a description of what we are going to do
codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait\:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
codename1.displayName=
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=
codename1.ios.release.certificate=
codename1.arg.ios.background_modes=,bluetooth-central,bluetooth-peripheral
codename1.android.keystorePassword=<actualPassHidden>
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.arg.ios.add_libs=;CoreBluetooth.framework
codename1.arg.ios.dsym=false
codename1.arg.android.release=true
roid.keystoreAlias=<actualAliasHidden>
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.android.keystore=<actualPathHidden>
codename1.arg.ios.pods=,Cordova
codename1.vendor=CodenameOne
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=
codename1.mainName=Main
codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword=
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=false
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=
libVersion=169
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/><uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/><uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
codename1.arg.ios.application_exits=false
codename1.secondaryTitle=CodenameOne_Template
codename1.description=
codename1.ios.debug.provision=
codename1.arg.build.incSources=1
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.version=2.0
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.arg.ios.plistInject=<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key><string>${foobarfoo}</string>
codename1.arg.android.debug=false
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=false
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=false
codename1.packageName=com.ijs.opkp
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: One of these values from codenameone_settings.properties is empty. If you will include the codenameone_settings.properties in the question I'll probably be able to answer that. Notice that you need to comment here after you edit the question so I will get notified...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added the codenameone_settings.properties file. Is there something missing? I don't remember what the file looked like when building worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking thru the entries in the properties vs. the XML it seems the `displayName` property is blank. I didn't check everything but that seems to be an issue.

Comment: I added a displayName. Then Netbeans warned me that I need to set an Android certificate. I set it up and now building works. Thank you.